# Permutations of a word

Tags: statistics

I was asked in class how many unique 5 letter combinations I can make out of the word "maths" i know that you can use the permutations formula to work out the maximum amount of combinations of this word but I'm not sure how the r (repetitions) works with this question, I know that n=5 but i don't know what r is.

So how would i apply the permutations formula to this example and others?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 5 distinct letters in the word " m a t h s ". So there are 5! = 120 5-letter words that can be formed using the letters of this word.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any difference between this and sets? and also what do I do when there is a condition? e.g "Must have M" 

a) How many 3 letter sets can be selected from the letters m, a, t, h, s? b) How many 4 letter sequences are possible that use the letters m, a, t, h, s at most once each and contains
the letter m?

Comment: @joe: nice !. I recommend you make another post with these questions. But for a), there are C(5,3) = 10 sets.

Comment: I will soon, but what is the C()?

Comment: made a new question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/721808/permutations-of-a-letter-sequence